# Find minimum, after one value

Tags: postgresql, minimum

Possible to find the minimum after one fixed value in postgresql?

Example:

```
Time_ID   Number
   1       100
   2       150
   3       200
   4       230
   5       240
   6       245
   7       250
```

I like to find the minimum after the ID 4. If i use the min(Number) function that case show me the 240 is the minimum, but that not true, because the 230 the minimum on the ID 4.

Have any option to include the ID 4also to the minimum search?

Thank you any help!

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on the requested solution. The result should be 240? Or 230?
What would be the result if e.g. the value of id=6 would be 75?

Comment: The result should be 230. Because I need to see the minimum on the ID 4 or later not before. If the ID 6 75 that case that is the minimum, because smaller than 230.

Comment: Sure. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75521720/find-minimum-in-row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following

```
select min(number) from demo where time_id >= 4;
```

gives you the required result

| min |
| --- |
| 230 |

I used the following schema and test data

```sql
create table demo (
    Time_ID   integer,
    Number       integer
);
    
insert into demo (time_id, number) values 
    (   1  ,     100),
    (   2    ,   150),
    (   3     ,  200),
    (   4      , 230),
    (   5      , 240),
    (   6      , 245),
    (   7      , 250);
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jymRCqoQ7qnDX2eEx45Dbp/0)

Comment: Great to here. Welcome to SO. The way to say "Thank you, this helped." is to upvote the answer. The way to say "Thank you, this is the correct answer." is to accept it as such by clicking the check mark. This also helps others coming across this question to decide if it still needs an answer and which are the "good" answers.

Comment: And if the ID change? Example: after every 4th of ID check again the minimum?

Comment: This sounds like a new question. You should just put it in a new question. If you leave a link here in the comments I'll be happy to try to answer it if I can.